# Как удалить элемент из хранилища?

Tags: python, python-3.x, обработка-данных

Как удалить элемент из хранилища при передаче `delete` в качестве аргумента?

Должно быть так: `delete VK` и такого элемента больше нет в хранилище.

Вот еще мини-вопрос: как полностью очистить хранилище?

Вот код:

```
import shelve, pyperclip, sys

msbShelf = shelve.open('msb')

if len(sys.argv) == 3 and sys.argv[1].lower() == 'save':
    msbShelf[sys.argv[2]] = pyperclip.paste()
    if msbShelf[sys.argv[1]] == 'delete':
        del msbShelf[sys.argv[2]]
elif len(sys.argv) == 2:
    if sys.argv[1].lower == 'list':
        pyperclip.copy(str(list(msbShelf.values())))
    elif sys.argv[1] in msbShelf:
        pyperclip.copy(msbShelf[sys.argv[1]])


msbShelf.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Примеры:

```
In [35]: db = shelve.open('test1')

In [36]: db['key1'] = 'val1'

In [37]: db['key2'] = 'val2'

In [38]: db['key3'] = 'val3'

In [39]: db['key4'] = 'val4'

In [40]: list(db)
Out[40]: ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4']
```

`.pop(key_name)` - возвращает элемент по ключу `key_name` и удалаяет его из объекта `shelve`:

```
In [41]: db.pop('key2')
Out[41]: 'val2'

In [42]: list(db)
Out[42]: ['key1', 'key3', 'key4']
```

возвращаемый элемент можно "тихо" проигнорировать:

```
In [43]: _ = db.pop('key3')

In [44]: list(db)
Out[44]: ['key1', 'key4']
```

полностью очистить хранилище:

```
In [45]: db.clear()

In [46]: list(db)
Out[46]: []

In [47]: db.close()
```

Comment: Не работает....

Comment: @Manvey, лаконично...

Comment: pop(<Ключ>[, <Значение по умолчанию>]) - удаляет элемент с указанным ключом и возвращает его значение. Если ключ отсутствует, то возвращается значение из второго параметра. Если ключ отсутствует и второй параметр не указан, то возбуждается исключение KeyError.

Answer (score 0):

Удалить элемент:

```
if len(sys.argv) == 3 and sys.argv[1].lower() == 'del':
    del msbShelf[sys.argv[2]]
```

Удалить все элементы:

```
if len(sys.argv) == 2 and 
sys.argv[1].lower == 'del':
    for item in msbShelf:
        del item
```